# can't figure out the error with the following code

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and trying to figure out the error within the following code

```
x = int(input("input x"))
y = int(input("input y"))

if x>y : 
x -= y
elif y>x:
x += y    
else if x==y :
print("y = ", y)
print("x= ", x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python throws compilation errors if code is not indented properly and `else if` is not valid in python the syntax is `elif`.

Errors :

```
File "test.py", line 15
  x -= y
  ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

```
File "test.py", line 15
  x += y
  ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

```
File "test.py", line 18
    else if x==y :
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Fixed code :

```
x = int(input("input x"))
y = int(input("input y"))
if x>y : 
    x -= y
elif y>x:
    x += y    
elif x==y :
    print("y = ", y)
    print("x = ", x)
```